# Children's book-- siblings, Michael Faraday, kid in a coma

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I have searched google in so many ways without being able to identify this children's book.

All I remember was that I read it in the US in the late 70's or 80's, there were 2-3 siblings, 1 girl and 2 boys, I think they were in England at some manor or mansion. The story was set in modern times (20th century) and there was a time travel element involving meeting Michael Faraday or someone related to him. One of the kids (the youngest?) somehow slips into a coma or dream where he sees himself  arguing for why he should be sent back to life. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Going out on a limb here, but [The Snowstorm](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0000CNGN5) by Beryl Netherclift?

Summary:

> Farthingales is Aunt Amethyst. The children agreed on that. She was
>   trying valiantly to save the gabled old house in the English
>   countryside, which was beset by taxes and falling into ruin. From the
>   first day of their visit, Caroline, Richard, and Kit were determined
>   to help -- and they soon found that the beautiful snowstorm
>   paperweight on the library mantel held the key. When the sun shone on
>   it in a special way, time and space were suddenly suspended and the
>   children found themselves confronted by ancestors from bygone eras,
>   including Michael, the boy who came from the year 1832 to meet them in
>   the present -- ancestors who held the secret of the ruin of
>   Farthingales. THE SNOWSTORM is a charming and exciting story, peopled
>   by vibrant characters whose personalities, regardless of their era,
>   are very real and very much alive.

It came out in 1967, involves time travel, an English manor, 3 children, a boy (ancestor?) named Michael, and the last name Faraday (Aunt Amethyst's last name, I believe from other reviews).